# How can I avoid SQL DB2 issue?

Tags: python, sql, database, db2

When I run this query by manually it execute correctly without any issue and I can get the store number and item number but when I use it in my framework and connect my scenario step to the Db2 it gives me an error. This is the query which one is I execute:::

`cursor.execute("select * from qs36f.DSTHSTP join qs36f.calendar on date_ccyymmd = dhindt where date_iso between(current date - 10 day) and current date and DHCUS# in (" + open_stores + ") and dhqtss>=1 and DHCLSS = " + class_nbr + " and dhsbcl = " + sub_class_nbr + " and ((dhqtss*dhrt5s)*DHPACK) <" + end_range + "")`

I don't know what is the issue here. This is error:::

```
cursor.execute("select * from qs36f.DSTHSTP join qs36f.calendar on date_ccyymmd = dhindt where date_iso between(current date - 10 day) and current date and DHCUS# in (" + open_stores + ") and dhqtss>=1 and DHCLSS = " + class_nbr + " and dhsbcl = " + sub_class_nbr + " and ((dhqtss*dhrt5s)*DHPACK) <" + end_range + "")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET. (-104) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

My expectations is I have to retrieve from database store number and item number.

Comment: Edit your question with the **exact** query you send to the database (to don't guess on which values your variables have) and data types of **all** columns participating in expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: What is the actual query you are using?

Comment: @user253751this is the actual query I run in Dbeaver it is running without any issue.:::::          select * from  qs36f.DSTHSTP 
join qs36f.calendar on date_ccyymmd = dhindt
where date_iso between(current date - 10 day) and current date
and DHCUS#>1 AND dhqtss>=1 and DHCLSS=21 and dhsbcl=3
 AND ((dhqtss*dhrt5s)*DHPACK) < 100

Comment: You provide contradictive information. `DHCUS#>1` for dbeaver and `.. DHCUS# in (" + open_stores + ") ...` in the code snippet. Again, please, modify you application to dump the real statement you send to the database server and show it here.

Comment: MarkBarinstein it is the real statement which is I execute in Dbeaver and I can get details whatever i need. BUt when I connect my scenario step to the Db2 and I send parameters "+open_ stores + "instead off Dhcus#> 1 and and etc. I have couple queries but for different items they are working as expected.

Comment: My last attempt to help. Modify your application like `stmt="select ..."; print(stmt); cursor.execute(stmt);`. Edit your question with the output of `print` and the error message you get.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I did but did not get error message   cursor.execute(statement)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET. (-104) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: I asked a number of times to print the exact statement you send to the database server from your application, but you haven't done it. The statement you run in dbeaver is clearly different from the one you use in the  application. Sorry,  but we probably don't understand each other, I don't know how to explain what I need in other words, and I can't help you anymore.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks I fixed it already. it was wrong because of the sequence of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are facing a syntax error. Having that your statement is:

```
select * 
from qs36f.DSTHSTP 
join qs36f.calendar 
    on date_ccyymmd = dhindt 
where date_iso between (current date - 10 day) and current date 
    and DHCUS# in (" + open_stores + ") 
    and dhqtss>=1 
    and DHCLSS = " + class_nbr + "
    and dhsbcl = " + sub_class_nbr + " 
    and ((dhqtss*dhrt5s)*DHPACK) <" + end_range + "
```

It's possible that you are not building it correctly. In such cases, try to remove one line from the `WHERE` clause and execute the query in order to find the one that is not correct.